# Temporary object created in case of an object declared and then assigned

Tags: c++

I have a user defined class Fixed, with a default constructor, a parameter constructor and an assignment operator.

When I declare an object and then assign it:

```
Fixed a;
a = Fixed( param );
```

I get:

1. call to default constructor (line 1)
2. call to parameter constructor (line 2)
3. call to assignment operator (line 2)
4. call to destructor (line 2)

Of course I could (and should) prefer initialization (`Fixed a(param)`) over assignment.
Yet I'm trying to understand what happens on line 2.
Is a temporary object created ?

Here is what i found about temporary object.

> In some cases, it is necessary for the compiler to create temporary
> objects. These temporary objects can be created for the following
> reasons:
> ...
>
> To store the return value of a function that returns a user-defined
> type.  **These temporaries are created only if your program does not
> copy the return value to an object.**

Here, the program does copy the return value of the object, so how come a temporary object is created ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is a temporary object created ?

Yes.

The expression `Fixed( param )` will create a temporary object. This temporary object will then be passed to the assignment operator of the `a` object.

The statement

```
a = Fixed( param );
```

is somewhat equivalent to

```
{
    Fixed temporary_object( param );
    a.operator=( temporary_object );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> To store the return value of a function that returns a user-defined type. These temporaries are created only if your program does not copy the return value to an object.

The line you mention is irrelevant. `Fixed(param)` is not a function call.

The line refers to something like:

```
Fixed f(param) {
  return Fixed(param);
}

...
Fixed a;
a = f(param);
```

In this case the line explains that you shouldn't get a temporary created to hold the result of `f` and then copy that to `a`. This would be in addition to what you've seen above.

Also experiment with optimization levels.